# How to remove negative index error in groovy code?

Tags: groovy, apache-nifi

I  have code  logic  inside  nifi processor (executeScript  processor) which  will  reduce log  files(in this  case  in my  log  files i  have  same  text  so  i want to remove  duplicates and i  try  to choose them  by  name  and   file  size),but  i sometimes ( not  always)  got  negative  index  error, **what  should  i change in my  code  to  make  it  work?**

```
import org.apache.nifi.processor.FlowFileFilter;
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
import groovy.json.JsonBuilder
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils

def flowFile = session.get();
def  n=0;
if(!flowFile)return
def size = flowFile.getAttribute('Size');
int value = size as Integer;
if((value/338)>=1){
def ffList = session.get(new FlowFileFilter(){
    public FlowFileFilterResult filter(FlowFile ff) {

        if( size == ff.getAttribute('Size') ){ n++; return FlowFileFilterResult.ACCEPT_AND_CONTINUE;}
       else{ return FlowFileFilterResult.REJECT_AND_CONTINUE; }
    }

});

session.transfer(ffList[n-1],REL_SUCCESS);
session.remove( ffList[0..-2] )
session.remove(flowFile);
}
else{
session.transfer(flowFile,REL_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: I'm assuming by negative index error you mean a `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`? What does that say about your index and array size?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check the size of list before accessing elements.

```
def ffSize = ffList.size()
if (n <= ffSize && ffSize >= 2) {
    session.transfer(ffList[n - 1], REL_SUCCESS)
    session.remove(ffList[0..-2])
    session.remove(flowFile)
}
```